# Scheduled Triggered Flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

So I am currently creating a scheduled triggered flow. Every time I debug it, when I checked the logs, the interview started by a different user instead of my profile which is a Sys Ad profile. Any idea on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 4):

As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5) by default the Automated Process user runs schedule-triggered flows.

> Now you can specify the default workflow user in your org’s process
> automation settings to run schedule-triggered flows. Previously, the
> Automated Process user ran schedule-triggered flows. If you don’t
> specify the default workflow user to run schedule-triggered flows, the
> Automated Process user runs them by default instead.

Please find the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&release=234&id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_versioned_updates.htm) for the same.

Comment: How do you change the Automated Process user?

Comment: @cropredy, With the winter '22 release, Scheduled Flow uses the Default Workflow User if the Default Workflow User is set. So if we set that setting  to other user the flow will run as that user. If that is not set it runs as Automated user

Comment: Would be great to [add that](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_versioned_updates.htm&type=5&release=234) to your answer

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, Updated the answer accordingly.